# how to handle mixed results using doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, query-builder

I am using symfony2 and Query builder. I get mixed results as a result of my query that follows. I know this is due to using aggregate functions in SELECT, but I DO NOT find any other way and this is exactly what I need. Any direction would be gratefully appreciated:

```
public function Inventory() {
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb
        ->add('select', 'i.id, i.name, SUM(pod.quantityorder) as quantityordered, SUM(it.quantity) as quantityreceived')
        ->add('from', 'AutokeenPurchasingBundle:Items i')
        ->leftJoin('i.purchase_order_details', 'pod')
        ->leftJoin('i.inventory_transactions', 'it', 'WITH', 'it.inventory_transaction_type = 1')
        ->add('groupBy', 'i.id')
        ->addGroupBy('it.item')
        ->addGroupBy('pod.item')
        ->add('orderBy', 'i.id');
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $query->useResultCache('my_cache_id');
    return $result = $query->getScalarResult();
}
```

Comment: I did figure it out by myself using native SQL :)